# Can I use a ViewBox as a Source for an Image in WPF?

Tags: wpf, viewbox

I have an icon that's defined in XAML and the root element is `Viewbox`. I would like to set that as a `Source` of an `Image` element.

I tried to set it directly as a source for an Image like...

```
<Button Margin='5'>
   <Image Source='{StaticResource IconKey}'></Image>
</Button>
```

But I get an exception. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Since they're the same fill, why haven't you combined the data from both paths into one geometry? You could then just put a 16 by 16 path in the button, set it's data to that new geometry and stretch to fill. I don't see the canvas, viewbox etc add anything useful

Comment: I don't know how to do that, I'm brand new to WPF! Could you show me that? @Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative. Instead of Using an `Image` inside the button I used `Button`'s `Content` attribute.

```
<Button Content='{StaticResource IconKey}' />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a big subject and tricky for beginners because there's so much "stuff" you need to get your head round.

I'll try and cover a few things around the subject. Hopefully that might reduce your confusion a little.

A Path uses data which looks a bit weird what with all that strange co-ordinate stuff. This can go directly in a path, or in a Geometry ( or a stream geometry ). If you use a geometry then that is re-usable for a red-whatever blue-whatever etc. It is also not a visual so you don't get caught out by visuals only being able to have the one parent - ie one use in any ui.

The way I'd usually go about this sort of thing is to obtain a single geometry.
Often out of syncfusion metro studio ( which is a free library ) but sometimes I use inkscape ( free ) to trace a bitmap or I get a path out a svg.

You can however combine two geometries.

In a resource dictionary merged by app.xaml you could have a geometry:

```
        <CombinedGeometry x:Key="TwoGeometriesInOne">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <Geometry>
                   M3,1.6675c0,-0.1795..... and the rest of your first geometry data
                </Geometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
               <Geometry>
                   M15.9289,7.776L5.285,....
                </Geometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>
```

Huge long strings mess up the site, but those two geometries should just have the M... through to the z of that data you're using for each path.

Use that in a button ( or any other content control )

```
    <Button Height="40" Width="40">
        <Path Fill="#3E79B4" Data="{StaticResource TwoGeometriesInOne}"
              Height="16"
              Width="16"
              Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Button>
```

Note that a path can just be used on it's own rather than in a canvas and sized, it can also be stretched to fit it's size or whatever the parent allows.

Consider also:

```
    <Button Height="40" Width="40">
        <Path Fill="#3E79B4" Data="{StaticResource TwoGeometriesInOne}"
              Stretch="UniformToFill"
              Margin="5"
              />
    </Button>
```

With a path you have fill and stroke. Stroke is the outline. If you want different coloured shapes in one "icon" then a drawingimage with multiple geometrydrawing would be more suitable because each geometryimage can have it's own brush.

Comment: Would it be easier if my image was an svg file?

Comment: Short answer is no. You can't just use an svg as the source for an image control. I think someone built a custom control you might be able to find. If you open an svg in inkscape you can just save as and choose xaml. You then open that file up and extract the geometries in it. Sometimes you can just open an svg in notepad++  https://liftcodeplay.com/2015/09/14/converting-vectorsvg-images-into-xaml/